# Creating multiple instances of a viewmodel in Prism/Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, prism

I have a prism/silverlight view and it is mapped to a tabitem in a tab control of my shell.
It looks like this.

```
<sdk:TabControl>
    <sdk:TabItem Header="User Portfolio" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
    <sdk:TabItem Header="Benchmark Portfolio" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="BenchRegion" />
</sdk:TabControl>
```

The view consists of a datagrid,textbox and a button such that the datagrid maps to an observablecollection in the viewmodel and when the button is clicked, the text in the textbox gets added to the datagrid(and the corresponding collection).

Now, I want to declare multiple instances of this view-viewmodel pair. That is, in tabitem "MainRegion" I want one instance. In tabitem "BenchRegion" I want another instance

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the container, and for each instance of the view model you need to use `IUnityContainer.ResolveType<>()` to initialize the instance (Make sure you register your types first `IUnityContainer.RegisterType<>()`). You can think of `ResolveType<>()` as Prism's form of a constructor. Then for the each view you need to set the datacontext to your initialized view model for that view.

**Edit** I should note that this is for Prism 2.0 I know that with Prism 4.0 there are alternatives to unity.

Comment: Although this is probably implied, but lastly, you need to add each view to the respective region.  An alternate approach would be to have the view type registered to each region; that way, when the regions are shown, instances of the views (and, if done properly with the view model as a dependency of the view, the view models) will be automatically created for each region.

Comment: yes I assumed that if he was using regions he knew to add the views to the regions :)